# put item of listView in preference activity

Tags: android, listview, preference

I have a list view , and I would like to implement a button for each item that if crushed makes visible that item in another activity ( preferenceActivity ) . What should I go and see to achieve this? There are guides ? thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPrefrences to change settings outside of a PreferenceActivity: [How to change state of a preference item from outside the PreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251667/how-to-change-state-of-a-preference-item-from-outside-the-preferenceactivity) 
I recommend reading this guide on Android Settings: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html